# Storing img src in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, onclick

When I click on an image, I want to store that particular images `src` in a Javascript variable. How can I do this? Keep in mind the `<a>` tag is there for the hover effect. So when I click on the `<a>` I want the image source of its sibling.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FVrTg/2

```html
<div>
    <img src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg/260px-YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg"/>
    <a href = "#"></a>
</div>

<div>
    <img src = "http://whatiscat.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/cute_cat_2.whatiscat.com_.jpg"/>
    <a href = "#"></a>
</div>
```

​

Comment: Do you mean the source as in the *image's data*, or just the `img src` attribute value? Like `$a.siblings('img').prop('src')`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the image's url in a js variable, or the actual binary data for the image in a js variable?

Comment: BTW looking for pure javascript (not jquery)

Comment: Blasphemy! There is no Javascript, long live jQuery! (Of course I'm kidding, I somehow made the leap automatically and the answers you got are probably my fault. Sorry. Also note, it is more complicated with pure Javascript DOM walking.)

Comment: Unless, of course, you store an `id` for the `img` you're referencing in a `rel` or `data-img-id` attribute on the `a`, which would greatly simplify the answer.

Comment: Interesting, I'd like to see how it could be done though, any takers? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    alert ( $(this).siblings("img").attr("src") );
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FVrTg/3/)

...

**UPDATE**

JS only - http://jsfiddle.net/FVrTg/7/

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var size  = links.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert( this.previousSibling.previousSibling.getAttribute("src") );
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Got a pure javascript way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var src = $(this).siblings('img').prop('src');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FVrTg/5/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to do this without using jquery?

Comment: How can I store the path of the image in JS variable for which the user has selected by clicking the browse button ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate event for `click` on `document`, for efficiency, and get the `parentNode` for `<a>`. Then grab the `<img>` and get the `src`. With `parentNode` you can safely add to your design without altering the code.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/NWD7f/

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {

    var a = event.target;

    if( a.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a' ) {

        var src = a.parentNode.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )[0].src;
        console.log( src );

    };

}, false );​
```

Comment: For every click on the page? I guess it's an approach. IMO, `document.getElementsByTagName` is a "cleaner" approach, and I still felt a little naughty suggesting that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Delegates are more efficient than an event on each image. It's how libraries, like jQuery, recommend handling events (and are pushing it with the `.on()` function).

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to be on the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), does it? (EDIT: Although, I can see what you're saying in the delegate sense. It just feels icky, I'll probably get over that I suppose.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yeah, that's just for easy demo purposes. I'd put an element around all the images. I was trying to leave his HTML as-is.

Comment: My whole answer revolves around manipulating the markup, using a `rel` (or a custom attribute as I mentioned that in a comment under the question) to link the `a` to it's corresponding `img`. Event attachment is better than my example's use of `el.onclick`. Old habits are hard to give up, but I think the `rel` gives the designer more latitude than DOM traversing, although both are useful at different times.

Comment: And, one day please God, let us all forget the lunacy of legacy DOM traversals in our joy at finally having `document.querySelector` and it's ilk being fully-supported across all relevant browsers needing support... Amen and Hallelujah!

Comment: Something else that just occurred to me, doesn't support need to demonstrated as well? Such as, `if (!document.attacheEventListener) document.attachEvent()...`?

Comment: I think that's a flawed concept for a number of a reasons, most of which is there is a current reality and this would/could be an unexpected gotcha for someone who doesn't know any better. At least mentioning an issue like this you're aware of I think is a best practice; standards are volatile and users are literal. I don't think these issues should be ignored as a matter of course, but how you see it is your business. `:)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13322/discussion-between-thinkingstiff-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will print the `img.src` out using `rel="img-id"` to relate the `a` to the `img`:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img id="img-1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg/260px-YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg"/>
    <a href="#" class="img-hover" rel="img-1"></a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        c_links = links.length,
        link;

    while (c_links--){
        link = links[c_links];

        if (link.className.indexOf('img-hover') > -1) {
            link.onclick = function(){
                var img = document.getElementById(this.rel);

                if (img) {
                    console.log(img.src);
                }
            };
        }
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ecXCX/